# Can installed packages (on Ubuntu) get removed from system during an update?

Tags: ubuntu

My apologies if this question seems dense - I'm fairly new to linux/Ubuntu.  I'm pretty sure I had installed libmdbodbc some time ago on my **Precise Pangolin** version of Ubuntu, but recently when I tried to use it, it's no longer there.

I tried to reinstall via:

```
sudo apt-get install libmdbodbc
```

but I get an `Unable to locate package libmdbodbc`.

It appears that [this library](http://lino.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/base/libmdbodbc) has been **"deleted"** from the Ubuntu repository.
I didn't *intentionally* remove this, so could it have been removed possibly when I clicked yes to install a bunch of security updates?

Does anyone have any insight into why it would be removed from the repository (or if/when it would be added back). I kind of require it, so what are my options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libmdbodbc1) the name of libmdbodc is now libmdbodbc1 starting in Precise. I suspect you were thinking of a previous Ubuntu installation or it's something that changed during the beta process for 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the package name has change to [libmdbodbc1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libmdbodbc1) in Precise.